# Why Auto-Dark-Mode doesn't work sometimes?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, dark-mode

I'm using the [2020 Intel MacBook Pro](https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-mac/macbook-pro/13-inch-space-gray-2.0ghz-intel-core-i5-quad-core-processor-with-intel-iris-plus-graphics-512gb#) and I'm facing the following problem.

The Auto-Dark-Mode of MacOS is not as stable as iOS or iPadOS. If I'm using a single app in foreground (probably Safari) and it's sunset time, the Auto-Dark-Mode works as expected, but when I'm working on a project so I have 5-6 apps opened together in foreground, Auto-Dark-Mode fails but the wallpaper goes to Dark-Mode (but the the apps doesn't), and it happened right now while I'm writing this post.

**Note:** When I toggle Dark-Mode manually after Auto-Dark-Mode fails, they goes to Dark-Mode as expected (if they have light mode, for example some apps like VS-Code don’t change their theme with system). I’ve faced this issue on Catalina as well.

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: I personally say in dark mode, but what program are you using that doesn't seem to change?  Is it just Safari or another program? Does that program support Dark Mode? Does the Safari site support Dark Mode as well?

Comment: When It fails, It does for all the programs. Then I have to manually go to System Preferences and set Theme to Light/Dark then to Auto Again, then It updates.

Comment: "Please tell me if my problem is a common one" doesn't solve a practical problem. Also, are you sure these 5-6 apps support auto-switching at all?

Comment: If you were to quit thee applications and relaunch them after the dark mode turns on, what happens?

Comment: @ErniePC12 I never tried that, because that procedure has more steps than simply updating the settings in System Preferences.

Comment: @ErniePC12 I prefer Light Mode on daytime and Dark Mode on night time.

Comment: I'm sensitive to bright light, I need dark mode. Even this site hurts at times. I am wondering if the applications might not know how to switch over to the other side. Websites that support dark mode will only switch when loading the content. Try relaunching the affected apps and see if they adjust after the switch.

Comment: @ErniePC12 there are some programs that injects JavaScript to force websites to turn dark, you should try them.

Comment: Well personally I think "when macOS creates the event for toggle theme" due to "heavy load on the cpu" macOS itself avoids to update the theme. and also I think it's specific to Intel Macs.

Comment: @nohillside It's not an opinion based question, it's a real issue of macOS since macOS Mojave.

Comment: I'm sure the problem is real. The question as written asks for opinions and experiences though, not for solutions. It also lacks important details as listed in the comments above. You've already been adviced on taking the Tour, please also read the articles in the Help Center (especially the ones about asking questions in https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far and what macOS version. Suggestions: find out whether all apps support dark mode (I had issues with the WhatsApp client), restart your Mac, try it in single user/safe mode, reset SMC/NVRAM/PRAM, create a different user try there, reinstall the programs, check if certain apps trigger it (try one by one), check if heavy load (CPU, RAM) has anything to do with it, if you can, re- or better clean install macOS, start from a different boot device,...

Comment: Well I have fresh-installed macOS BigSur, fresh installed apps (not from time machine). Nothing helped. And as I said it doesn't happen when there is only 1 or two apps in foreground. Since iOS have silicone and it works so smooth that's why I think it's specific to Intel macs, and I need non-intel-mac user's "opinion" to make sure what I'm writing is true.

Comment: @nohillside I think I have improved my question. Please review.

Comment: The question was put into the review queue after your first edit but didn‘t receive enough votes to have it reopened. It looks much better with your recent edits.

Comment: I am running a 2017 15" MBP. It has never failed as far as I know to toggle dark mode. There are much lower-spec'd Macs out there that have support for this feature, I **really** doubt that it has anything to do with it being Intel. Please edit all the info you state here in the comments into your question, so others don't have to dig through comments. If you think its performance issue, then I would suggest you check the activity monitor and also start testing if it happens with every app, one by one.

Comment: I also noticed this issue on my fresh install of macOS Monterey 12.0.1. Only wallpaper was darkened, but app windows were not. I had to manually switch on dark mode, then all apps windows were switched to dark mode as well. After this manual intervention, The *General -> Appearance* was changed to *Dark* automatically (which is more annoying than this bug already).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is quite trivial: *because **macOS** is **buggy** even in such core features*.

A workaround I use when I face similar glitch in the evening: going to system settings, not forcing dark mode, but "forcing" light mode instead, then returning setting back to "Auto". Switches immediately. But more likely the next evening you'll have to do it again. Why? — *Because **macOS** is **buggy** even in such core features*.